# Revive/care for Yen Ben lemon tree

Tags: lemons

Need some help/advice for my Yen Ben lemon tree, location is New Zealand.

I have been watering about once a week, usually with lemon tree food added.
I am in a pretty sheltered apartment area, the tree gets direct sunlight for about 4 hours in the morning, 8am-12pm ish.

The branches are quite dry.

Any tips to revive / care for this tree in its current condition?
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your tree is dead.  The only way to know is to scratch the bark off in various places.  If it is green under the bark that part of the tree is still alive.  If it is brown, black or grey underneath that part is dead.

With clean pruners remove all the dead part of the tree.  Then put the tree in a location it can get more sunlight.  Only water it if the soil is dry.

If the tree is alive it might leaf out again.  It would be good to know how long it has been without leaves.  If it has been many months then the tree is dead.   Evergreen shrub if under stress might loose all their leaves, but they will grow back if the stress if removed.

Only fertilise actively growing plant.  During the growing season.  Typically Spring through summer.   Do not fertilise it any other time.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The tree has been without leaves for about three months or so.

The tree has green under the bark in most places, except the furthermost branches. I will trim the dead parts and try to move it to a place it can get more sun.

Thanks again.